# My System Doesn't boot well

Tags: boot, startup, bootloader

"A start job is running for hold until boot process finishes up (21mins 55s/ no limit"

The above is the message i receive when i hit the ESC button. My laptop is still booting a for 18mins now.

I don't know what to do. 
I installed Ubuntu yesterday and i am a novice at it.

Comment: It could be installing updates, just be patient

Comment: Try to run `fsck /dev/sdX`, where X is the partition where ubuntu is installed. You will have todo this from a live usb, because the partition must be unmounted.

Comment: @PonJar I have never known(could be possible) of ubuntu to install updates during booting.  My experience is that ubuntu will ask to install updates sometime after booting.

Comment: @crip659, yes on reflection I think you are right. I have Ubuntu running in a virtual machine. I don’t use it much but when I do use it after a period of inactivity it takes forever to boot and get to a usable desktop. When this happens the processes that are taking all the resources are to do with apt and update manager and the like. I had interpreted that to be down to update settings in the software updates. Looking at it closer this morning I think it’s more a case of housekeeping going on and not literally updates being applied.